# Error on test with React Js - TypeError: source.on is not a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, jestjs, vitest

I have a post request with multipart/form-data.
Everything works, but the tests don't.
When I run the tests, I get: **TypeError: source.on is not a function**.

**this is my request:**

```
images.forEach(async (image) => {
      const config = {
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
          'Authorization': `Bearer ${user}`
        }
      }

      const formData = new FormData();
      formData.append('workId', JSON.stringify(workId));
      formData.append('image', image.image, image.image.name);

      const data = {
        work_id: formData.get('workId'),
        url: formData.get('image'),
      }

      await api.post(`${baseUrl}/work/api/images/create/`, data, config)
      .then((r) => {
        console.log(`created successfully with status code ${r.status}`);
      })
      .catch((e) => {
        console.error(`this is the error: ${e.response.status}`);
      })
    })
```

**this is my test**

```
  it('should returns success on create images', async () => {
    // mock the response
    server.use(
      http.post(`${baseUrl}/work/api/images/create/`, () => {
        return new HttpResponse(null, { status: 201 })
      }),
    )

    const user = userEvent.setup();
    
    handerImagesWorkManager(1, 'user');

    // mock the images
    const images = [
      new File(['text'], 'image-test.png', { type: 'image/png' }),
      new File(['text'], 'image-test2.png', { type: 'image/png' }),
    ];
    const inputUpload: HTMLInputElement = screen.getByTestId(/upload_images/i);
    await user.upload(inputUpload, images);

    // spy
    const spy = vi.spyOn(console, 'log');
    const submitButton = await screen.findByDisplayValue(/upload all images/i);

    await user.click(submitButton);

    expect(spy).toHaveBeenCalledWith("created successfully with status code 201");
  });
```

I know the problem is with sending the file/image, because when removing the image from the formData the test works.
I've already tried modifying the test and request code, but when one works, the other doesn't work.

Comment: FYI your use of `Array.prototype.forEach` is bad. Instead use `Array.prototype.map` as in `return Promise.all(images.map(async image => {}))` or `Array.prototype.reduce` as in `return images.reduce((promise, image) => promise.then(async () => {}), Promise.resolve())`. Sometimes fire and forget is what you want but you should push it to the very edge of your system so that it can be tested and individual callers have to decide whether or not to fire and forget

Answer (score 1):

I solved it. I wasn't using formData correctly. Instead of passing the formData in the request, I was separating the data.

```
const formData = new FormData(); 
formData.append('work_id', JSON.stringify(workId)); 
formData.append('url', image.image, image.image.name);

await api.post(`${baseUrl}/work/api/images/create/`, formData, config)
```